# How could I use regular expressions to extract the following markup?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example suppose # denotes a special word as follows

I took a #lovely trip to the #zoo today.  We had a #wonderful time. With RegEx is it possible to extract something like

```
#lovely#zoo#wonderful
```

Comment: Should `#n&*nhj23` be matched too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `string.match`

```
var str = "I took a #lovely trip to the #zoo today. We had a #wonderful time"
str.match(/#\w+/g); // #lovely,#zoo,#wonderful
```

Might want to tweak the regex to include numbers and symbols depending on your needs.

`/#[\w\d]+/g` for letters and digits, `/#\S+/g` for anything that is not whitespace.

EDIT: I'll add that the `g` at the end means that it will find all matches and not only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

There is the regex answer. And then, there is the `split` answer. The following works:

```
var s = 'I took a #lovely trip to the #zoo today. We had a #wonderful time.'
var tags = s.split( '#' ).map( function ( str ) {
    return str.split( ' ' )[ 0 ]
} )

// Now, tags[0] is not good, so let's splice it
tags.splice( 0, 1 )

console.log( tags ) // ['lovely', 'zoo', 'wonderful']
```

So, yeah, it's a little more verbose than the regex solution. I find it more elegant though.

PS: you guessed it, I don't like regex!

Comment: Do you honestly find this mess more elegant than a four character regex?

Comment: I don't like regex ._. and I don't think it's a mess.

Comment: Well, I do like regexes when they are the right tool for the job at hand, and this is such a time.